# Connecting HTML with Python

Tags: python, html

I tried to link my HTML file with Python code.

I tried this

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open_new_tab("data.HTML")
```

It returned my HTML page in Firefox..

But i need to return to my Python program to execute remaining lines

But when I closed this browser, it closes my Python script too.

And I tried to link my Python program by,

```
<a href="c://user/elcot/pychat.py">go to Python</a>
```

it returns to text editor not to terminal...

But I need to return to terminal.

I need the solution

Comment: I would suggest you to use flask framework

Comment: What do you mean by "but i need to return to my Python program to execute remaining lines"? `webbrowser.open_new_tab` should not block until you close the browser. The rest of the script should continue executing. What do you mean by "connecting HTML with Python"? Please describe what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: No bro...it didn't executing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone described, you need to use one web framework (like flask, django others) to run python code. Or the second solution is using CGI(http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/).

For the second problem(want to keep running python code after browser is closed), I want to advice to use Selenium.

Cheers, John